# Visual Studio C++ C2022. Too big for character error occurs when trying to print a Unicode character

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode

When I try to print a Unicode character to console. Visual Studio gives me an error. How do I fix this and get Visual Studio to print the Unicode character?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "\x2713";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `\x2713` is too large for a `char`. You want `L"\x2713"`

Comment: `\x2713` is too large to store in a `char` type. Try `std::wcout << L"\2713";`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, are you sure? G++, Clang, and MSVC all think it's [one character](https://godbolt.org/z/cbW5cqW4s)

Comment: @ChrisMM when I follow your link, clang and MSVC both error out completely and gcc displays a very scary warning.

Comment: @MarkRansom, on mine, g++ issues a warning, and clang/msvc treat it as an error, but they all make it clear it's one character.

Comment: On Wandbox,, using g++ 10.1.0, this statement `std::wcout << L"\x2713";` compiles and runs, and treats the escape sequence as a single wide character. It prints a `?` to the console, but I would expect that.

Comment: @ChrisMM I guess we're talking past each other.  Yes it's a single character, but it doesn't fit into a `char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, `\x2713` is too large for a single character. If you wanted two characters, you need to do `\x27\x13`, if you wanted the wide character, then you need to prefix with `L`, i.e. `L"\x2713"`, then use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout`.

Note, from the C++20 standard (draft) `[lex.ccon]/7` (emphasis mine):

> The escape \ooo consists of the backslash followed by one, two, or three octal digits that are taken to specify the value of the desired character. **The escape \xhhh consists of the backslash followed by x followed by one or more hexadecimal digits that are taken to specify the value of the desired character. There is no limit to the number of digits in a hexadecimal sequence.** A sequence of octal or hexadecimal digits is terminated by the first character that is not an octal digit or a hexadecimal digit, respectively. **The value of a character-literal is implementation-defined if it falls outside of the implementation-defined range defined for char** (for character-literals with no prefix) or wchar_t (for character-literals prefixed by L).

Essentially, the compiler may treat that character how it wants; [g++ issues a warning, and MSVC (for me) is a compiler error (clang also treats as an error)](https://godbolt.org/z/cbW5cqW4s)

Comment: If I read your clip of the standard correctly, there's no way to put a hex escape in the middle of a number.  That's unfortunate.  I always thought `\x` would stop after 2 digits.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think you are correct - from here [lex.string](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.string#nt:string-literal) to [lex.ccon](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.ccon#nt:escape-sequence) to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.ccon#nt:hexadecimal-escape-sequence

Comment: That version, which is newer than the version I have, still indicates more than two digits are read, but makes the program ill-formed (compilers should error on it based on that standard). I think that version is intended for C++23 though.

Answer (score 0):

`\xNNN` (any positive number of hex digits) means a single byte whose value is given by `NNN`; unless in a string literal or character literal prefixed by `L` in which case it means a `wchar_t` whose value is given by `NNN`.

If you are looking to encode a Unicode code point, the the syntax is `\uNNNN` (exactly 4 digits) or `\UNNNNNNNN`  (exactly 8 digits).  Note that this is the code point, not a UTF representation.

Using the `u` or `U` forms instead of `L` avoids portability problems due to `wchar_t` having different size on different platforms.

To get well-defined behaviour you can manually specify the encoding of a string literal, e.g.:

```
std::cout << u8"\u2713" << std::endl;
```

which will encode the code point as UTF-8.  Of course you still need a UTF-8 aware terminal to see meaningful output.

Without the encoding prefix then it is up to the compiler (I think) in what way to encode the code point.

See:

- [Escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)
- [String literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)